# Scrolling view on textbox click

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I have some textboxes on my scrollview.When user clicks on the textbox that scroll view should scroll automatically.So I can avoid some textboxes hiding behind virual keyboard.Somebody please help to solve this.

Comment: are you trying My code of Answer...?

Answer (score -1):

```
Try below code my friend....

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 scroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0,25);//you can set position of y(25 here) anything as per your confort and how much do you want to scroll.

}
```

Let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy coding!!!!